# WebStorm Node.Js Sequelize Model type hint

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, sequelize.js, type-hinting

I'd like to know how to type-hint node.js sequelize models in WebStorm for better code completion.

At least I was able to figure out, how to get code completion for model properties. But I'm missing the model functions from sequelize.

This is how far I got:

models/exampleModel.js

```
/**
 * @module ExampleModel
 * @typedef {Object}
 * @property {ExampleModel} ExampleModel
 */


 /**
 *
 * @param sequelize {sequelize}
 * @param DataTypes {DataTypes}
 * @returns {Model}
 */
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var ExampleModel = sequelize.define('ExampleModel', {
       id: {
          type: DataTypes.BIGINT.UNSIGNED,
          primaryKey: true
       },

       someProperty: {
          type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
          defaultValue: true
       }
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
               ExampleModel.belongsTo(models.AnotherModel, {foreignKey: 'id'});
            }
        }
    });
    return ExampleModel;
};
```

models/index.js

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @module models
 * @typedef {Object} models
 * @property {ExampleModel} ExampleModel
 * @property {AnotherModel} AnotherModel
 */

var db        = {};

// code that automatically fills db with models from files
// resulting in something like { ExampleModel : ExampleModel, AnotherModel: AnotherModel}

module.exports = db;
```

Now I'm able to type something like

```
var models = require(__base + 'models');
models.Ex // Webstorm suggets "ExampleModel"
models.ExampleModel. // WebStorm suggets "id", "someProperty", "classMethods" (the last one is weird, but doesn't matter)
```

and get code completion for the models and their properties.
Now I'm missing sequelize methods like "upsert", "create", ...

Does anybody know how to get code completion for those also?

Answer (score 1):

I usually add fake method for improve IDE autocomplete

```js
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

// eslint-disable-next-line
function enableAutocomplete() {

  /**  @type {Model|Address|*} */
  db.Address = require('./address')();

  /**  @type {Model|Group|*} */
  db.Group = require('./group')();

  throw new Error('this function for IDE autocomplete');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside WebStorm 2019 hover over your Sequelize include:

```
require('sequelize');
```

You should see the yellow lightbulb. Click the yellow lightbulb and you be able to select "Install TypeScript definitions for better type information"

This feature is also documented inside the WebStorm docs, the example there is for express.js 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html